# Navigation Controller Issue: View not loading after pushViewControlleranimated called

Tags: iphone, ios4

Folks,
 New to iPhone development so I greatly appreciate your help.  I have been looking at documentation and trying many things to get my navigation controller functionality working but can't.

Here's the situation.  I have an app delegate which sets its root controller to be a navigation controller:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

self.window.rootViewController = self.mainViewController.navController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

The navigation controller is a property of the mainviewcontroller because I intend to take the user to a map view (associated with a mapviewcontroller) only when they select an item in a tableview owned by mainviewcontroller.  I can't yet think of a graceful way to notify the appdelegate about a table row selection, hence I am trying to handle this in the mainviewcontroller.

In the mainviewcontroller init function:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{

self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];
    mapController = [[MapViewController alloc] init];
}
return self;
}
```

In mainview controller, when the user selects an item from the tableview, I call:

```
[self.navController pushViewController:mapController animated:YES];
```

The view associated with my mapviewcontroller never appears.  Any ideas what's going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
[self.window addSubview:self.mainViewController.navController.view];
```

Before

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. I then added a line sending the subview to the back so the mainview would load first, but this also doesn't work. Not sure if there is some fundamental design pattern I am violating.  The mapview will show if I push it on the navigation stack in mainviewcontroller's init, because the app delegate then calls the makewindowkeyandvisible, which calls loadview and so on.  But this doesn't happen when I respond to a user table cell selection. Is there additional code I should post here? Thanks.

Comment: OK, some progress.  I added:                            self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:navController.view];
    [self.navController pushViewController:mapController animated:YES];  and this seems to work.